# methods which return the general working experience

Tags: java

Can you explain me, how to solve this task as like pseudocode? 
I try to write something but not sure about this

Create classes `Employee` and Manager with methods which return the general
working experience and payment for work done. Give your suggestion about 
relations between classes(is-a, has-a, use-a, etc) Find solution for avoiding 
of duplicate code. Write well commented code with examples of using these classes.

- Wrire code for reading and writing collection of these objects from (into) file.
- Find employee with maximal working experience.
- Find employee with maximal payment.
- Write code for handling the incorrect format of incoming file.

  ```
  class Employee {
  private String name;
  private int experience;
  private double payment;

  // Getters and setters for the 3 attributes

  public Employee(String name, int experience, double payment) {
      this.name = name;
      this.experience = experience;
      this.payment = payment;
  }

  public class Manager extends Employee {

      public Manager(String name, int experience, double payment) {
          super(name, experience, payment);
      }

      Manager manager = new Manager("Sue", 23,3500);
      Manager manager1 = new Manager("John", 22,3000);
      Manager manager2 = new Manager("Q", 12, 3200);

      public double maxPayment() {
          double maxPayment = 0;

          if(manager.getPayment() > manager1.getPayment() && manager.getPayment() > manager2.getPayment()) {
              System.out.println(manager.getName());
          }
          else if(manager1.getPayment() > manager.getPayment() && manager1.getPayment() > manager2.getPayment()) {
              System.out.println(manager1.getName());
          }
          else {
              System.out.println(manager2.getName());
          }
          return maxPayment;
      }

  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the methods `maxPayment` and `maxExperience` as `static` because they are not related to a particular instance, you'll need to create in your main method some employee/manager and give them to the method throught a list for ex:

```
public static double maxPayment(List<Employee> list) {
    return list.stream().mapToDouble(Employee::getPayment).max().getAsDouble();
}

public static double maxExperience(List<Employee> list) {
    return list.stream().mapToDouble(Employee::getExperience).max().getAsDouble();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Manager manager = new Manager("Sue", 23, 3500);
    Manager manager1 = new Manager("John", 22, 3000);
    Manager manager2 = new Manager("Q", 12, 3200);
    Manager employee1 = new Manager("Fred", 2, 3000);
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(manager, manager1, manager2,employee1));

    System.out.println(Manager.maxPayment(list));      //3500.0
    System.out.println(Manager.maxExperience(list));   //23.0
}
```

---

The way with `for-loop` would be :

```
public static double maxPayment(List<Employee> list) {
    double maxPay = 0;
    for (Employee e : list)
        maxPay = Math.max(maxPay, e.getPayment());
    return maxPay;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a very nice solution. Can you suggest some resources to learn java, and solve similar tasks (I mean what exactly i should know to solve this task)?

Comment: Read tutos, about loops, basics, I don't have ones to propose because I learned Java at school so i have no readings to propose, but there is a lot on the web